# Django: Getting column max value as Integer

Tags: python, django, max

I have this:

```
maxAux = Auxi.objects.all().aggregate(Max('nroAux'))
```

Then I need to add +1 to its value, but doing:

```
maxAux = maxAux+1
```

will throw an error since `aggregate(max` returns a string value like `{'nroAux__max': 5}` and I only need this number 5.

Please avoid asnwering about id or django default autoincr column. I really need to make additions to my column `nroAux`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/) actually returns a dictionary, and you can get the value same way as getting a value from dictionary using a key. For example (by using [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)):

```
maxAux = Auxi.objects.all().aggregate(max_val = Max('nroAux'))  # providing a key max_val

maxAux.get('max_val')
```